# How to use scala MapWrapper in java

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to add items to a scala map using the MapWrapper object but im having trouble initializing the MapWrapper. This was working fine with scala-library-2.9.1 but when upgrading to scala-library-2.10.5 its asking for an extra paramters "Wrappers". Does anyone know where I can find good documentation on the scala library for java?

```
scala.collection.Map<String, Object> topics = new scala.collection.immutable.HashMap<String,Object>();
        MapWrapper<String, Object> topicsWrapper = new MapWrapper<String, Object>(topics);
```

Comment: You should not be trying to call scala code from Java. There are so many synthetic/bridge methods etc, that you will go nuts making it a success

Comment: unfortunately I have no choice. Im using the kafka api which has a lot of scala code. Here is the specific code in trying to use this in: `Properties 
  scala.collection.Map<String, Object> topics = new scala.collection.immutable.HashMap<String,Object>();
  //MapWrapper<String, Object> topicsWrapper = new MapWrapper<String, Object>(topics);
  conn.createMessageStreams(topics);` The createMessageStreams accepts a scala collection. i need to add 1 item to the collection but im not sure how to add it.